# Draw ER digram for similar case

Tags: entity-relationship

1.Several students from different departments may participate one project. Each project has at least one student member.

2.Each student may or may not participate the projects, but one student can participate several projects at the same time.

In 1st statement, the relationship of student and project is **M-1**. But in the 2nd statement, the relationship of student and project is **1-M**

If I want to express their relationship in a single ER digram, should I use the M-1 or 1-M? Or is my ER diagram wrong?

[ER Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMvcR.png)

Comment: I think you make it a little bit complicated. Without knowing the exact exercise you were given I would think that since there are many students and each one can attend to many projects the relationship is M-N . But maybe I am wrong

Comment: The exercise advice me to use the entity of project and student only. I treat these two statements into two cases for simplification. So I think the first case is 1 - M